# Transform an array of objects into an array of object ids

Tags: numpy

I have a list with several objedos arranged in tuples of 3 objects ...

```
l = [(ob1, ob2, ob3), (ob1, ob3, ob4), (ob4, ob5, ob6), ...]
```

With numpy I can leave this list flat

```
a = np.array(l)
a = a.ravel()
```

I almost got an array of ids with `a.tobytes()`

But I'm still not having success :\

**How to transform an array of objects into an array of object ids?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is stopping you from using the `id` function? Besides, what objects are you talking about? I'm asking because tuples are actually objects too.
However, assuming you're talking about ids for obs, here you go:

```
object_ids = map(id, np.asarray(l).flatten())
```

**EDIT:**

Oh and actually if you want an array of object ids, then perhaps you should go like this:

```
get_ids = np.vectorize(lambda obj: id(obj))
array_of_obj_ids = get_ids(np.asarray(list_of_objects).flatten())
```

Comment: Well, I've efficiently gotten a list of ids through `np.frombuffer(a.tobytes(), dtype = 'u8')` but I really liked the `vectorize` function so I'll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @Mano-Wii I'm glad to help! Yeah in truth, my solution seems to be a bit more concise. It's not that obvious what  `np.frombuffer(a.tobytes(), dtype = 'u8')` does. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to copy the contents of the array, you can use this hack with ctypes:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

def switch_funcs(func1, func2):    
    from types import FunctionType
    assert isinstance(func1, FunctionType)
    assert isinstance(func2, FunctionType)

    size = FunctionType.__basicsize__

    func1_ptr = (ctypes.c_char * size).from_address(id(func1))
    func2_ptr = (ctypes.c_char * size).from_address(id(func2))

    store = (ctypes.c_char * size)(*func1_ptr)
    func1_ptr[:] = func2_ptr[:]
    func2_ptr[:] = store[:]


def dummy(*args, **vargs):
    pass

a = np.array([(ob1, ob2, ob3), (ob1, ob3, ob4), (ob4, ob5, ob6)])

switch_funcs(dummy, np.core._internal._view_is_safe)
b = a.view(dtype = 'u8')
switch_funcs(dummy, np.core._internal._view_is_safe)

print(b)
```

It temporarily removes the check that prevents the change from dtype object to uint64